# How to change the order of showing data in MFMailComposeViewController

Tags: iphone, ipad, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I have email functionality in my App. Along with the message body I attach an image data in the mail. While we do [self presentModalViewController:emailController animated:YES]; , it present a view in which, first the message body will be there and then the attachement data/image.

How can I change the order in which the mail showed. I need the image should be shown first and then the message body should follow. If anyone knows please reply immediately.

Thank you in advance. :)

Comment: This is possible: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10069288/308315

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The MFMailComposeViewController reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html) clearly states that the image is attached after the body and above the signature

```
 addAttachmentData:mimeType:fileName:

Adds the specified data as an attachment to the message.
- (void)addAttachmentData:(NSData*)attachment mimeType:(NSString*)mimeType fileName:(NSString*)filename
Parameters

attachment

    The data to attach. Typically, this is the contents of a file that you want to include. This parameter must not be nil. 
mimeType

    The MIME type of the specified data. (For example, the MIME type for a JPEG image is image/jpeg.) For a list of valid MIME types, see http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/. This parameter must not be nil.
filename

    The preferred filename to associate with the data. This is the default name applied to the file when it is transferred to its destination. Any path separator (/) characters in the filename are converted to underscore (_) characters prior to transmission. This parameter must not be nil.

Discussion

This method attaches the specified data after the message body but before the user’s signature. You may attach multiple files (using different file names) but must do so prior to displaying the mail composition interface. Do not call this method after presenting the interface to the user.
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible beacuse `MFMailComposeViewController` is inbuilt that is provided by Apple, and we can only use it as it is, Not modified

Although you can create your own custom Mail Composer Controller...