# How to set first Image after Some Text in Email body?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I am using MFMailComposeViewController for sending the Email,

With this code I am able to get the Image, But image comes after the Text Detail,
I wan't  First Image and after Text,

Here is my code,

```
   MFMailComposeViewController *mail = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    mail.mailComposeDelegate = self;

    if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {
        //Setting up the Subject, recipients, and message body.
        [mail setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:Emailid,nil]];
        [mail setSubject:@"Receipt"];

        NSData *photoData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation([UIImage imageNamed:@"Gift.png"], 1);
        [mail addAttachmentData:photoData mimeType:@"image/jpg" fileName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"photo.png"]];

        [mail setMessageBody:@"Receipt" isHTML:NO];
        NSString *emailBody;




        emailBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@
                     "<br>Purchase Amount:            </br> "      "$  %@"
                     "<br>Amount Received:        </br> "      "$  %@"
                     "<br>Change:    </br> "      "$  %@"
                     ,AmountData,txtAmount.text,ChangeAmount.text];  


        [mail setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:YES];
```

Please any body suggest me How can i do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

as of my knowledge this is the default behavior of the mfmailcomposeviewcontroller instead of just adding image as attachment you can do as below to show image first just to create body part

```
(void)createEmail {


NSMutableString *emailBody = [[[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@"<html><body>"] retain];
   [emailBody appendString:@"<p>Some email body text can go here</p>"];
   UIImage *emailImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myImageName.png"];
   NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(emailImage)];

   NSString *base64String = [imageData base64EncodedString];
  [emailBody appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<p><b><img src='data:image/png;base64,%@'></b></p>",base64String]];
  [emailBody appendString:@"</body></html>"];
    NSLog(@"%@",emailBody);

 //mail composer window
    MFMailComposeViewController *emailDialog = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    emailDialog.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    [emailDialog setSubject:@"My Inline Image Document"];
    [emailDialog setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:YES];

    [self presentModalViewController:emailDialog animated:YES];
    [emailDialog release];
    [emailBody release];
}
```

this is shown [here](http://www.roseindia.net/answers/viewqa/Mobile-Applications/20037-MFMailComposeViewController-image-attachment.html)

Comment: Thank's Alok, I just added my  base64String code  in my aEmail body and its working Fine.

Comment: With this imageData base64EncodedString, i able to show the image in iPhone mail detail but not able to get the Image in Gmail Account, How can i solve that problem, Any suggession?

Comment: actually i dont have much knowledge about it too

Comment: i think i got one answer just check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527351/how-to-add-an-uiimage-in-mailcomposer-sheet-of-mfmailcomposeviewcontroller-in-ip) out the first accepted answers discription

Comment: @TheiOSDev Thanks for the answer. Magic line  --->  NSString *base64String = [imageData base64EncodedString];